# What ways are there to comb a torus?

Tags: differential-geometry, moduli-space

Modulo diffeomorphisms, what are all possible nonvanishing vector fields on the two-torus?

Comment: Here's a guess: Say a curve winds $n$ times around in the latitude direction and $m$ times in the longitude directions and $\gcd(n,m)=1$. I expect there is a way to comb the torus parallel to that curve.  And maybe there are no others (where we consider two equivalent if a homotopy or something like that moves one to the other). ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: I'm not sure if you want to talk about modulo diffeomorphisms. The question then becomes a question of dynamical systems, which will presumably be much harder to answer. If you just want modulo homotopy, because the tangent bundle of the torus is trivial, we're counting homotopy classes of maps $T^2 \to (\Bbb R^2 \setminus \{0\})$.  This is in bijection with $\text{Hom}(H_1(T^2),\Bbb Z) \cong \Bbb Z^2$.

Comment: I think the question should ask modulo diffeomorphism isotopic to the identity, not modulo diffeomorphism. I'd suspect that they're all the same up to diffeomorphism.

Comment: I really want to know "modulo diffeomorphism", but if "modulo homotopy" is more interesting please feel free to add an answer to this case as well :-)

Comment: I think modulo diffeomorphism is more interesting! I just can't say anything about it.

Comment: I don't what you mean with two-torus..a closed compact of genus 2..isn't it?

Comment: The two-dimensional torus. A surface with genus one.

Answer (score 6):

This approaches an answer, but doesn't completely settle the question.

Classifying nonvanishing vector fields on a torus is at least as complicated as classifying line fields (pass to the subbundle of $T(T^2)$ that the vector field spans) up to diffeomorphism. I don't know whether these problems are equivalent. I have the vague feeling that the answer is yes but no real reason to think so.

Because line fields are one-dimensional, they're integrable. That is, a line field on the torus is the same thing as a codimension 1 foliation.

In particular, there are uncountably many different foliations up to diffeomorphism; Kronecker foliations of the torus with irrational angle $\theta$ are *rarely* diffeomorphic. See [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/178073/40804). In particular, each $T_\theta$ can only be diffeomorphic to countably many others.

By theorem 4.2 [here](http://www.map.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/Foliations#Foliations_of_surfaces) we have a decent idea as to what line fields on tori look like. Let's think about case 2); case 1) is fairly straightforward.

There is a Reeb component. We can pick a diffeomorphism so that this Reeb component is some standard Reeb component (say, the Reeb component is $[0,1/2] \times [0,1]$, thinking of the torus as a quotient of the unit square $[0,1] \times [0,1]$. Now we have to think about the foliations on the annulus $[1/2,1] \times [0,1]/\sim$; that same link says they're unions of Reeb components and suspensions of foliations. This is probably as good a classification as you're going to get.

(One should be a little worried about smoothness here when we're doing diffeomorphisms near the boundaries of each of these annuli. I don't know whether there's a way to make sure these diffeomorphisms are actually smooth everywhere.)

Comment: Does that link really say that differenty Kronecker foliations are diffeomorphic (apart from the obvious case where the slopes are in the same orbit)?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez I forgot the word "rarely"! Probably an important word to remember here. Thank you.

Comment: Haha :-) ${}{}$

Comment: That result imples that there are also many diffeo classes of vector fields, as a conjugacy of vector fields gives a conjugacy of the 1-dim distributions they span.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Right, that's what I was trying to say in the second paragraph. I don't know how many vector fields there are up to diffeomorphism in a fixed line bundle though.