# When are differential forms related by a base space automorphism?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, differential-forms, smooth-manifolds

Let $w$ and $u$ be nowhere-vanishing smooth differential forms fields of degree $n$ on a smooth manifold $M$ (aka smooth sections of $\Omega^n(M)$).

**When does there exist an automorphism $f: M \to M$ such that $f^*u = w$?**

Intuitively - can one always massage the base space $M$ so that $u$ gets pulled back to $w$? If not, can this hold by placing some additional constraints on the forms? Are there simple counter examples for this?

Comment: An $f$ does not always exist. For example, on $M = \mathbb{R}$, $u = dx$, $w = xdx$. The pullback of $u$ by any diffeomorphism of $M$ will be a nowhere-zero form, whereas $w$ has a zero.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese Good example, although I think to get less trivial answers I should  edit my question to restrict to nowheter-vanishing forms

Comment: For 1-forms this is equivalent to asking when nonvanishing vector fields are diffeomorphic. This is already complicated for the torus. See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1445330/98602). For nonvanishing n-forms I believe they're diffeomorphic iff they have the same volume.

Comment: For volume forms on compact oriented manifolds (i.e $dim M=n$), the famous Moser theorem tell you that to such form are related by a diffeomorphism if and only if they have the same volume.

Comment: The punchline of my comment is that away from n-forms I expect this to be very hard.

Comment: @Thomas: Do you know of a reference for this theorem?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese I'm not Thomas but [here](http://www.math.tecnico.ulisboa.pt/~mabreu/GD/moser.pdf)'s the Moser paper